# Junit to test soft keyboard using ResultReceiver

Tags: android, junit

I am new to android. In my activity in an android library, I am hiding the soft keyboard when 'done' button is clicked. I am doing this in 'onKeyUp'. I want to write a JUnit test case to test if the keyboard is hidden. I am planning to do that by passing ResultReceiver object to hidesoftInputFromWindow and comparing the resultcode in onResultReceiver.

@Override

public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

```
    InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    ResultReceiver result = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()){
    @Override 
    public void onReceiveResult(int r, Bundle data) {
                //Keyboard hidden
        }
        };
    try {
       imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(teamText.getWindowToken(), 0, result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem is, when the activity is started from an application, the 'onReceiveResult' is getting the callback. But when I start the activity from a JUnit ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 subclass, onReceiveResult is not getting the callback.

Can anyone please help me or point me in some direction?